What if the step attribute and stepUp(step) method both are defined
I was experimenting with the step property and stepDown , stepUp method of a date input.
While experimenting I stumbled upon the following. But I can not rationalize the output.
Here is the code I tried.
const date = document.querySelector("input[type='date")
const stepUp = document.querySelector("input#stepUp")                            
const stepDown = document.querySelector("input#stepDown")

stepDown.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    date.step = 10
    date.stepDown(20)
})
stepUp.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    date.step = 10
    date.stepUp(20)
})



"input[type='date" < there's something missing in this selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/stepUp
